# preventDefault() not working, page continues to Reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working in React I have a form component loading into a primary component.  Props are passed from the primary component to the form.  The handleInput function is working, but the page re-loads when the form is submitted.  'event.preventDefault' is inside of my submit function.

```js
  handleInputChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    
    if (event.target.type === "checkbox") {
      if (!this.state[name]) {
        this.setState({
          [name]: value
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          [name]: ''
        });
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({
        [name]: value
      });
    }
  };

  handleFoodFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    console.log("submitted")
  }
```

-- My form has three checkboxes and two single dropdown selects.

Render showing function in form component

```js
  render(props) {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Container>
        <form className="mt-4" onSubmit={this.props.handleFoodFormSubmit}>
```

I have also tried

```js
  handleFoodFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("submitted")
  }
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: so you are getting console.log statement ? (handleFoodFormSubmit) method is getting called ?

Comment: Do you have a submit button? Can you clarify if you any handlers attached to that button? Can you share the code for that?

Comment: The console.log within the handleInput function fires, but the page reloads before I can determine if the console.log in the handleSubmit fires.  I have a submit button `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`.